# How do I extract the numbers from string in C?

Tags: c, string, parsing

Following are the strings provided by the user to me:

```
"1 20";
"1 203";
"1 2030";
```

in the above examples `1` is query and `20`, `203`, `2030` are the numbers to be extracted. How can I extract them in C language?

Comment: Have you done any basic research? Many variations of "extract numbers from string" have been asked and answered many times here and on other sites. Not to mention C books and tutorials. Did you find *anything* that you could use? Did you make *any* attempt at the code based on what you can find and understand?

Comment: `strtok` and `strtol`   Thats it.

Comment: [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) and [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) are the two tools that most programmers use for this. Personally, I recommend `strtol`, as that function is more robust. If you use `strtol`, you can first read the first number, and `strtol` will tell you where that number ends, so then you can call `strtol` a second time from that new position to read the second number. It will automatically ignore leading [whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to parse a string containing numbers. If you expect the string to have a fixed format with 2 integers, the simplest solution is to use `sscanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int parse2numbers(const char *str) {
    int a, b;
    // sscanf returns the number of successful conversions
    int n = sscanf(str, "%d%d", &a, &b);

    if (n == 2) {
        printf("success: a=%d, b=%d\n", a, b);
        return 1;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        printf("failure: only one number provided: a=%d, str=%s\n", a, str);
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == 0) {
        printf("failure: invalid format: %s\n", str);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("failure: encoding error: n=%d, str=%s\n", n, str);
    return 0;
}
```

If the string can contain a variable number of integers, you could use `strtol()` to parse one integer at a time:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void parse_numbers(const char *str) {
    long a;
    char *p;
    
    for (;; str = p) {
        errno = 0;
        // strtol returns a long int
        //        updates `p` to point after the number in the source string
        //        sets errno in case of overflow and returns the closest long int
        a = strtol(str, &p, 10);
        if (p == str)
            break;
        if (errno != 0) {
            printf("overflow detected: ");
        }
        printf("got %ld\n", a);
    }
    if (*str) {
        printf("extra characters: |%s|\n", str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have not tested it but I think theoretically this should work:

```
int rows=2, columns=4 // defining length of array
char ch[rows] [columns] = {"1 90"}, {"2 90"}; // creating two dimensional array for sample data
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { // looping throw first dimention

// this only works if data is sorted and there is no missing indexes in between like [1 200] [3 200] will not work but [1 200] [2 200] should
    char* index;
    if ( ch[i] [0] != itoa(i+1, index, 10) ) // checking if index does not match the row then skip this iteration and move to next one.
        continue; 
    for ( int j = i+2; j<columns; j++) { // looping through second dimension
        printf("%c\n", ch[i][j]); // printing that second dimension
    }
}
```

Comment: ISO C does not have a function `itoa`. That is a platform-specific function. Please note that the question does not refer to a specific platform.

Comment: `char ch[rows] [columns] = {"1 90"}, {"2 90"};` does not compile

Comment: well its been long since I used c style strings but they are character arrays or character pointers I just tried to illustrate logic as I mentioned it is not supposed to be a copy paste coz i didn't test it.

Comment: plus about ```itoa``` I didn't know that.